# Broken lock on flat cable connector, can it work without?

Tags: ribbon-cable

I tried to replace the camera unit on my Samsung SM-C101 phone. It is connected to the phone's motherboard with two flat cables, that fasten and un-fasten through a little switch in the connector.

You can see the two connectors in the following picture, I circled them in yellow.

[image: Connectors]

You can see the little black switches on the left of the connectors. Unfortunately the two switches broke and the flat cables do not stay still. I can fix that with some tape, but my question is:

Without the two black flaps, does the cable make contact anyway? Or does it need to be pressed?

I'm asking this because the new replacement camera unit does not work. It pops in an out (it is a zoom lens) but then I get a "Camera error" message.

The main culprit are of course these connectors, I'd like to know more about how they work.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yep, those cable do need to be latched to work reliably. I'm sorry for your phone (I also have broken a couple of those in the past and I feel your pain).

Answer (score 2):

Those seem to be Flip-Lock connectors:

[image]

These connectors are designed with [ZIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_insertion_force) feature, meaning very little force is applied to the cable before it is locked, making it impossible to have a reliable connection when the lock is broken.

What is happening to your camera does look like an unreliable connection.

Comment: thank you for your input. It has been fixed by taping a small piece of thin plastic (from a plastic drinking cup!!) on the connector to make it thicker

Comment: I understand the camera is not a life-saving device, so I won't rant about reliability here. I'm just glad you could fix it. Just remember it's not ZIF anymore, so vibrations and repeated cable repositioning will quickly kill the cable or the connector.

Comment: of course, but it was either that or change the motherboard (I doubt anyone would go so far as to desolder and replace the ZIFs)
I hope it lasts as long as possible :)